# converting base 4 code to letters

Tags: c

im working on an assmebler project that i have and i need to translate binary machine code that i have to a "weird" 4 base code for example 
if i get binary code like this "0000-10-01-00" i should translate it to "aacba"

00=a

01=b

10=c

11=d

i have managed to translate the code to 4 base code but i dont know how to continue from there or if this is the right way to do it,...

adding my code below

```
void intToBase4 (unsigned int *num)
{
  int d[7];
  int j,i=0;
  double x=0;
  while((*num)>0)
  {
    d[i]=(*num)%4;
    i++;
    (*num)=(*num)/4;
  }
  for(x=0,j=i-1; j>=0; j--)
  {
    x += d[j]*pow(10,j);
  }
  (*num)=(unsigned int)x;
}
```

Comment: Lookup table...

Comment: You need some sort of way to tell the converter how many base 4 numbers are included in the passed in array.  You also should have a way of returning the "string" you have created.

Comment: "i get binary code like this "0000-10-01-00" What does this means? Is this a string? Tell us more.

Answer (score 0):

I've included a little 32-bit to num to letter converter for you to grasp the basics.  It works a single "32-bit number" at a time.  You could use this as a basis for an array based solution like you have half way done in your example, or change the type to be bigger, or whatever.  It should show you roughly what you need to do:

```
void intToBase4 (uint32_t num, char *outString)
{
  // There are 16 digits per num in this example
  for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
  { 
    // Grab the lowest 2 bits and convert to a letter.
    *outString++ = (num & 0x03) + 'a';

    // Shift next 2 bits low
    num >>= 2;
  }
  // NUL terminate string.
  *outString = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more universal one:
Usage:
value - value to decode, buff - buff where result string will be stored, numofwrds - number of fields to be decoded, ... fields sizes in bits

example "xxxxyyvvzz": - 4 bits, two bits, two bits, two bits

```
decode(v, buff, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2);
```

---

```
char dictionary[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz";

char *decode(unsigned int value, char *buff, int numofwrds, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    int *fieldsizes = malloc(sizeof(int) * numofwrds);
    int bitsize = 0;
    char *result = NULL;

    if (fieldsizes != NULL)
    {
        va_start(vl, numofwrds);

        for (int i = 0; i < numofwrds; i++)
        {
            fieldsizes[i] = va_arg(vl, int);
            bitsize += fieldsizes[i];
        }
        va_end(vl);

        for (int i = 0; i < numofwrds; i++)
        {
            unsigned int mask, offset;

            mask = (1 << fieldsizes[i]) - 1;
            offset = bitsize - fieldsizes[i];
            mask <<= offset;
            buff[i] = dictionary[(value & mask) >> offset];
            bitsize -= fieldsizes[i];
        }
        free(fieldsizes);
        result = buff;
    }
    buff[numofwrds] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Omg, you used va args in an example for someone who isn't a C coder.  You are very mean :)

Comment: Basics actually.